# Installation Problems: Ubuntu won't install next to Windows on my SSD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, ssd

sorry if my problem may seem trivial to most of you. I'm doing my first few steps on Linux again, after trying it out and dropping it again in my early adolescence.

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my private/non-critial-usage PC and am stuck. Here's what I did and as many data as I suppose to be relevant:

- I copied Ubuntu 17.10 x64 on an USB Stick using LiliUSB
- UEFI-booting the stick gave me a warning, stating that BIOS operating systems may be present and will not be able to boot afterwards. I cancelled the Installation, no data was written.
- I booted the stick as UFD and didn't get the error. I was now at "Installationsart" (Should be "installation method").
- The installation software recommenced to install Ubuntu next to Windows. That's what I wanted, click next.
- On the next chapter, the installation software only offered my second drive (hdd) to install ubuntu to. That's not what I wanted, so "back"
- Choosing "something other" to see what devices and partition tables are present for the software. There is my ssd and my hdd. The ssd has my Windows 10 and two other small, shady Partitions that should be related to Windows 10 recovery at least. sda is Windows 10 and has >100GB free.

I don't feel like manually partitioning for my installation. I'm afraid for SSDs to need some different tool for this, to have some extra loops for EFI and LEGACY+EFI, and to have trouble uninstalling it if the user experience will be unexpectedly bad.

I pretty much picked Ubuntu for my trial because I remembered it to be very focused on casual desktop users. While I, being in that peergroup am now stuck, I guess it's still a valid attribution because I have this place to ask for help :-)

I'll add some additional data, just in case:

```
MB: MSI B150M Mortar
CPU: Intel i5-6500
GPU: XFX RX470 4G
RAM: Corsair 2*4DDR4 2133mhz
SDA: Samsung EVO750 250GB
SDB: Western Digital WD500 500GB
```

Comment: SSD is just another drive, a few settings may be something you want to do. System is UEFI, so best to install in UEFI mode. Windows in UEFI mode requires extra partions, they are not 'shady'. You should use Windows partitioning tools to shrink Windows and make unallocated space. But NTFS needs 30% free to work well.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: I would use 16.04 instead of 17.10 which becomes obsolete soon. Also I would boot the Live USB and select "Try before installing" to ensure all the hardware is supported correctly. The 100 GB free on the SSD is more than enough for Ubuntu. First you need to go into Windows and shrink about 30 to 50GB so that Ubuntu can create a partition on the SSD for it to use.